# Cannot get the needed value from Ruby On Rails custom route

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My route looks like this:

`get '/asssets/v/:id', to: 'assets#process', as: 'asset_external'`

In my controller I have:

```
def process
  params[:id] # returns `v/123` instead of `123`
end
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Can you please show me how are you using the route in view?

Comment: Thank you @Ahmad, I figured it out it was an mistake in another part of the application.